# Apollo mutation not appearing in props

Tags: reactjs, meteor, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Here's my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { gql, graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo';

export class Test extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("this.props: " + JSON.stringify(this.props, null, 2));
    return null;
  }
}

const deletePostMutation = gql`
  mutation deletePost ($_id: String) {
    deletePost (_id: $_id)
  }
`;

export const TestWithMutation = graphql(deletePostMutation)(Test)
```

This seems like a pretty simple example, but when I run it the props are empty:

```
props: {}
```

Comment: Looks good. Maybe if you return an empty div it works

Comment: The function is there. The problem is JSON.stringify is not showing functions ‍♂️.  At least this question serves as an example of how to do it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code in the question above is a good example of how to do it.  The function **is** there. The problem is JSON.stringify is not showing functions ‍♂️. At least this question serves as an example of how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **return** statemant in your resolve function of mutation in your schema.

Example:

```js
resolve: function(source, args) {
  // Add the user to the data store
  exampleCollection.insert({
      category:    args.category,
      subCategory: args.subCategory,
      title:       args.title,
      description: args.description,
      salary:      args.salary,
      region:      args.region,
      created_at:  new Date()
    });

  // return some value.
  return args.title;
}
```